# How to execute a function from an array acting as a queue whenever a function is added to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a pair matching algorithm, I add a function call to an array which acts as a queue and execute one by one to avoid conflicts when matching. I want something to keep and eye on the queue and execute when a function is added to the queue. Like a routine checking if the array has any element? Can I do this using something like `resque` library?

Edit: let me make my problem clear. I have a game using `socket.io` where i match 2 users together and share some data with them Users click pair button and pair function is called. But the problem is that on high peak times user A gets match with B and B gets matched with C. This should not happen. So I queue the pairing function calls using and array. I want the array to execute each function call one after another. There will be times when the array will be queue empty for long time.

Comment: Are you in control of the code that adds the functions to the array? If so, you could either execute a callback function that handles execution whenever you add something or add an event listener and dispatch a CustomEvent when you add a function.

Comment: Yeah I have control of the code. If i try to execute whenever I add something, this can result in parallelism. I don't want that. What I tried is adding a infinite loop which checks the array but that seems messy even though in works .

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, so you shouldn’t have to worry about parallelism.

Comment: okay that's cool

Comment: So no problem when the users click the pair button at the same time?

Comment: If that happens, the currently running code will finish executing before the click event is processed. You can read about how JavaScript processes asynchronous events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this simple code to enque functions with parameters and context, and execute them later can fit your question...

```js
/**
 * Wrapping function code
 *
 * fn - reference to function
 * context - "this" context
 * params - array of parameters to pass to the function
 */
var wrapFun = function(fn, context, params) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
}

// the function to be wrapped
var pairMatch = function(userA, userB) {
    // your matching code here...
    console.log('matching user', userA.name, 'with user', userB.name);
}

var user1 = { name: 'Alice' };
var user2 = { name: 'Bob' };
var user3 = { name: 'Charlie' };
var userN = { name: 'Zoe' };

// wrap the function (the parameters must be in an array)
var fun1 = wrapFun(pairMatch, this, [user1, user2]);
var fun2 = wrapFun(pairMatch, this, [user3, userN]);

// create an array and append your wrapped functions to it
var funQ = [];
funQ.push(fun1);
funQ.push(fun2);

// shift all items (functions) in the array, and execute one by one...
while (funQ.length) {
    (funQ.shift())();   
}
```

Comment: But in this case the while loop ends if there are no functions in the array. right?

Comment: Correct. You should integrate the while loop inside the logic of your app... The code does not implement the whole application, but only explains how to queue functions with context and parameters, and execute them in squence at a later time...

Comment: Is there any way to know which function belong to which user? Like give a key or something to a function

Comment: You can pass any number of parameters to `pairMatch` function... For example, you could pass an additional key as the first parameter... So:

`var pairMatch = function(key, userA, userB) {`

and

`var fun1 = wrapFun(pairMatch, this, ['keyA', user1, user2]);`

...

Comment: (funQ.shift())();  is there a way to get return value from the wrapped function?

Comment: `let returnValue = (funQ.shift())();`